# Передача файла через UDP с помощью Socket

Tags: c#, wpf, сокет, udp, .net-6

Попытаюсь ввести в курс дела
Я пишу 2 программы, 1й это консольный сервер, 2й это приложение `WPF`. Приложение отправляет запрос сделать скриншот серверу и сервер получив сообщение делает скриншот и отправляет его по байтам в приложение чтобы отобразить этот скриншот но у меня где-то ошибка которую я не могу найти.

Вот код сервера

```cs
var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            var listenerEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 27001);
            EndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            listener.Bind(listenerEP);

            var buffer = new byte[ushort.MaxValue];

            Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
            Size size = new Size(bit.Width, bit.Height);
            Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bit);
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();

            while (true)
            {
                var len = listener.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref endPoint);
                // приём сообщения сделать скрин
                if (Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, len) == "screen")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Clear();

                    // получаем скриншот
                    graphic.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, size);

                    // преобразовываем сскриншот в биты
                    byte[] imgByte = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bit, typeof(byte[]));
                    Console.WriteLine($"imgByte Length {imgByte.Length}");

                    // создаём массив для отправки битов по частям
                    ArraySegment<byte> segment = null;
                    int indStart = 0;
                    int elem = 1000;

                    int count = 1;
                    int byteCount = imgByte.Length;

                    // получаем количество пакетов для отправки
                    while (true)
                    {
                        byteCount -= 1000;
                        count++;

                        if (byteCount < 0)
                            break;
                    }

                    // отправляем количество пакетов которые будут отправленны
                    byte[] bytesCount = BitConverter.GetBytes(count);
                    listener.SendTo(bytesCount, SocketFlags.None, endPoint);
                    Console.WriteLine($"countBytes {bytesCount.Length}");

                    // отправка массива битов скриншота
                    do
                    {
                        segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(imgByte, indStart, elem);
                        listener.SendTo(segment, SocketFlags.None, endPoint);
                        indStart = elem;
                        elem += 1000;

                        if (imgByte.Length % 1000 < 1000)
                        {
                            elem = imgByte.Length % 1000;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine($"count {count--}");

                    } while (count != 0);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Send! {imgByte.Length}");

                }
            }
```

А это код приложения

```cs
var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            EndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 27001);


            // отправка команды сделать скрин
            client.SendTo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("screen"), endPoint);


            // приём сообщения о количестве отправленных пакетов
            byte[] countBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            client.ReceiveFrom(countBytes, ref endPoint);
            int count = BitConverter.ToInt32(countBytes, 0);


            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[count * 1000];
            byte[] img = new byte[count * 1000];
            ArraySegment<byte> segment = null;

            // приём массива байтов скриншота
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(imageBytes, i*1000, 1000);
                client.ReceiveFrom(segment, ref endPoint);
            }



            // собираем скриншот из байтов обратно
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();
                Screen_shot.Source = bitmapImage;
            }
            client.Close();
```

данные между приложениями отправляются но полученный скриншот в итоге получается таким
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, я знаю что такое UDP и лучше бы использовать TCP, но домашнее задание таково, что это надо сделать используя Socket(UDP), именно используя сокет с UDP
(Вот само задание:
Программа должна состоять из двух частей: клиента и сервера.
Для написания программы следует использовать протокол UDP.
Сервер должен уметь отправлять скриншоты клиенту.
Клиент (в котором также будет встроен сервер для приема скриншотов) должен быть приложением WPF и получать скриншоты от сервера и отображать их на экране.
)

Можете ли подсказать где тут ошибка? Может я как-то не правильно отправляю скрин или не правильно принимаю. Я уже несколько часов пытаюсь найти проблему и не получается.

Comment: Взятие работает правильно, проверял сохранением самого скриншота.
Преобразование тоже правильное, выводил количество байтов консоли
Проблема либо в передаче, хотя он передаёт все байты, либо в приёме что более вероятно

Comment: Версия дотнета какая?

Comment: Версия .NET 6.0

Comment: Avatar Killer если задание полностью смог сделать, мог бы код полностью показать? хочу это задание разобрать